# How to dynamically define and generate serializers in django

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-serializer

I am working on an event driven service which receives a lot of events and these events have payload. I want to validate all payloads with serializers. Since the events types and huge in numbers, I don't want to define serializers in code for every event as that would require a new release every time a new event is added or an existing one is changed.
So, is there a way I can define these serializers dynamically for each event in a table instead of code and  use it to validate the event payload ?  Any new additions/changes can be done in the table itself.

Comment: Please consider adding a sample of the code you have tried

Comment: Sorry I am new to django and do not have any idea how to proceed with this. Can you please help in giving direction

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.